# MongoDB - Spring Boot : Read from primary and secondary DB together

Tags: mongodb, spring-boot, spring-data-mongodb

I am using SpringBoot to connect to MongoDB and perform read/write operations.
I have used MongoDB uri for configuring the properties.
Now my use case is that I want to read from primary and secondary DB at different places.
Is there a way to do this in SpringBoot without having to configure two different MongoClient and MongoTemplate Beans? By easily setting any properties or fields?

I know i can set readPreference in MongoDB uri but that will be a generalization. I want to specifically read from primary and secondary DB using the same SpringBoot-autoConfigured MongoTemplate.

Comment: Take a look [Multiple Databases](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-data-jpa-multiple-databases)